# <TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable rint method

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I get the followin error when I tey tu run the file from terminal:

I am using python 3.7 and working on a windows 10 system.

The error apears while running a virtual environment where all the requirements have been installed.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\52331\PycharmProjects\Q-Learning-for-Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable rint method

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 29, in <module>
    data = np.around(get_data())
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in around
  File "C:\Users\52331\PycharmProjects\Q-Learning-for-Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3224, in around
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
  File "C:\Users\52331\PycharmProjects\Q-Learning-for-Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 70, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\52331\PycharmProjects\Q-Learning-for-Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 47, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable rint method
```

Comment: what code is run that creates this error

Comment: any answer of this post ?